# CKFinder - Clicking 'send it to the server' when uploading an image does nothing

Tags: 7, files, wysiwyg

I am trying to get CKFinder to work correctly. The file manager and related functionality is recognized.  When I click the little image in the toolbar to upload a photo the window comes up properly. I then select 'upload, browse (to select the file)' and then I click 'Send it to the server.'

At that point, nothing happens - the upload / file field disappears and greys out.

Nothing is actually uploaded, so, upload is not working.

Any thoughts as to why this might be happening?

Comment: EDIT - I am getting this error as well when I click the 'browse server' button "System Error: It was not possible to load the XML response from the web server. The server returned an empty response." maybe the issues are related?

Comment: Use IMCE instead of CKFinder, it's closer to the Drupal...

Comment: after tearing half my hair out for the past few hours, I am wondering if there is a better solution.  Currently, I am using CKEditor and CKFinder. SHould I keep CKEditor and use IMCE for images? or Should I abandon the CK series alltogether for another / better solution? What do you recommend

Comment: Did you check for Javascript errors in the console ?

Comment: yea, no JS errors at all to be had, nor does the Apache error log have any php or possibly other related errors. weird

Comment: IMCE is the same as CKFinder, but it hasn't troubles that came from CKFinder...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this, as inspired by Nikit's comment, was to not use CKFinder at all.

CKFinder / CKEditor combination has to be one of the most frustrating experiences in all of Drupal, and it is the one thing I dread on each project. I have no idea why it has to be so complicated.

I kept CKFinder and used IMCE as suggested. The recipe works great; no complicated configuration; and is a much better module, in my opinion, for managing user images and file content.  I would suggest trying it as well if you find CKE and CKF as frustrating as I do.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting JS errors and PHP errors after following the README.txt "Installing CKFinder" instructions. The JS error was the following:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)
>
> http://example.com/sites/all/modules/contrib/ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=Init&type=Images&id=Full

The PHP errors was:

> PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [function.require]:   Failed opening
>   required '../../../../../includes/filemanager.config.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/php/pear') in
>   /var/www/example.com/htdocs/sites/all/modules/contrib/ckeditor/ckfinder/config.php
>   on line 86, referer:
>   http://example.com/sites/all/modules/contrib/ckeditor/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?Type=Images&id=Full&CKEditor=edit-body-und-0-value&CKEditorFuncNum=563&langCode=en

It was pretty obvious that I had incorrectly included the filemanager.config.php file. In my case, CKFinder is located under /sites/all/modules/contrib/ckeditor/ckfinder so I updated the require statement in /sites/all/modules/contrib/ckeditor/ckfinder/config.php (as indicated in the ckeditor module README.txt) to  read:

```
require_once '../../../../includes/filemanager.config.php';
```

The filemanager.config.php is now properly included which fixed the issue.